# Rails callback error on create, save in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was developing my app when suddenly, an error popped in the console.

When using Rails console, I can't create, nor save a model. This is the error I get :

```
rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
              result = result = _callback_before_71
```

I reverted to a previous commit in git and it still doesn't work...

Full error message:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
              result = result = _callback_before_71
                      ^
/Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
/Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
/Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:400:in `class_eval'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:400:in `__run_callback'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/validations.rb:228:in `run_validations!'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `block in run_validations!'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__1438787982741389732__validation__2895348434256153547__callbacks'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/validations.rb:195:in `valid?'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/validations.rb:69:in `valid?'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/validations.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:45:in `create'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.3-p374
```

Comment: Any specific model, or all models? It would be nice to see some application code related to this.

Comment: Can you post the line you're using to save?

Answer (score 0):

Tonight I ran into the same problem, so I'm going to take a guess at the code that was causing your issue.  My assumption is that your model that was failing to save was using the has_secure_password class method.  In my experience, it appears that when you attempt to perform predefined validations (validates_presence_of, validates_length_of etc) on the temporary 'password' field, you encounter the above error.  When I switched to a validation similar to what urgetopunt uses in this [blog post](http://urgetopunt.com/rails/2012/11/12/validate-password-presence-has-secure-password.html), the error went away.

Hopefully this helps you.